# When making accessible tabs with ARIA, is it OK to remove 'hidden' content from the DOM?

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria

Various ARIA guides on making accessible tabs suggest using `aria-hidden="true"` to hide all the tab panels except the 'current' one.

The idea is you use JavaScript to handle clicks on the tabs, updating which of the tab *panels* have the `aria-hidden="true"` attribute. And you use some CSS like `[aria-hidden] { display: none }` for the visual part.

But another way to 'hide' elements is simply to take them off the DOM. If you're using something like React, this is a practical solution – you just only render the currently active tab panel. So there would be no need to use `aria-hidden="true"`, because the tab panels in question don't even exist.

My question: is there any problem doing this, from an accessibility standpoint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No problem at all.  Remember that ARIA attributes are for when normal html semantics can't be used.  `aria-hidden` is used when you want to hide something from the screen reader that can't be hidden using standard CSS.  If you're using `display:none`, then that element is already hidden from the screen reader and `aria-hidden` is not needed.

Comment: Thanks. Just found the [first rule of ARIA](https://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#firstrule) which says basically this